# take a snapshot on HTML Video at specific time in jquery

Tags: jquery, video, screenshot, snapshot

Hi i doing the app for take a screenshot of the HTML Video at the specific time, i do have the function that work but it's not stable. When I take the screenshot fire many time.

Here the function: Refer at [How to take youtube screenshot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26603618/how-to-take-youtube-screenshot)

```
var VideoSnapper = {

            /**
             * Capture screen as canvas
             * @param {HTMLElement} video element 
             * @param {Object} options = width of screen, height of screen, time to seek
             * @param {Function} handle function with canvas element in param
             */
            captureAsCanvas: function(video, options, handle) {

                // Create canvas and call handle function
                var callback = function() {
                    // Create canvas
                    var canvas = $('<canvas />').attr({
                        width: options.width,
                        height: options.height
                    })[0];
                    // Get context and draw screen on it
                    canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(video, 0, 0, options.width, options.height);
                    // Seek video back if we have previous position 
                    if (prevPos) {
                        // Unbind seeked event - against loop
                        $(video).unbind('seeked');
                        // Seek video to previous position
                        video.currentTime = prevPos;
                    }
                    // Call handle function (because of event)
                    handle.call(this, canvas);    
                }

                // If we have time in options 
                if (options.time && !isNaN(parseInt(options.time))) {
                    // Save previous (current) video position
                    var prevPos = video.currentTime;
                    // Seek to any other time
                    video.currentTime = options.time;
                    // Wait for seeked event
                    $(video).bind('seeked', callback);              
                    return;
                }

            // Otherwise callback with video context - just for compatibility with calling in the seeked event
            return callback.apply(video);
            }
        };
```

the function i use

```
$('#btn_SnapCapture').bind('click', function() {
            var canvases = $('canvas');
            VideoSnapper.captureAsCanvas(media, { width: 250, height: 250, time: snaptime }, function(canvas) {
                $('#screen').append(canvas);
            });
            $(this).unbind('click');
        });
```

Please help me to fix the issues

Comment: P.S. variable "media" is the $('video');

Comment: `if (prevPos) {` ... and out of nowhere there's a `prevPos` :)