# Automatically Pause When Visiting Youtube URL

Tags: youtube, chromium, delphi-xe

I was tasked to capture the image on a specific time when visiting youtube. So far I haven't got any success using chromium. For example, i need to capture the image of a video exactly after 180 seconds, i will have to visit this URL ***https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Biagyb7AcK8&t=180s*** , what i did is to issue pause command OnChromiumLoadEnd but it fails depending on internet speed.. Are there any command to make video is paused on a specific time?

EDIT
here is my code OnChromiumLoadEnd:

```
begin
  CEFWindowParent1.SetFocus;
  Sleep(200);
  keybd_event(Ord('K'), 0, 0, 0);
end;
```

Comment: Can you add what have you tried? - I remember read a post here on Stack Overflow about a similar issue: get a screenshot of the video at specified time - I can't recall if that post had an accepted answer, tbh. Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66422682/12511801) or check any of these posts from this [search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Byoutube%5D+screenshot).